# Topological sort order of graph

Tags: topological-sort

I am having a hard time figuring out the ordering found after topological soft of this given graph. if anyone could explain to me I would appreciate it!  [image: Click here to see the graph]

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a topological sort, you run a depth-first search on the graph. Note: for this to work, it must be a Directed Acyclic Graph. This graph is directed (edges go one-way) and acyclic (there are no cycles), so topological sort works here. You can start at any node that has no incoming edges, and then once you complete a node (that is, you've already visited all of the node's children), you add it to the front of your topological ordering. Note: There **can be** multiple topological orderings for a DAG.

Here, A is the only node with no incoming edges. Let's run our DFS where, when given a choice between children, we pick the one that comes first in the alphabet.

A goes to B, which goes to C, then D, then G, then F. **F** has no children, so that is finished and will be the last thing in our topological ordering. We go back up to G, which takes us to **H**, which also has no children, so we put it before F in the ordering. From here, we continue the DFS until the ordering is complete.

I won't solve it fully for you, but I hope you can see how to complete the ordering.